# How to get a view to dynamically correspond with an object?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm writing an app that holds workouts. A Workout object has an array of Exercise objects. Each exercise has a name and a few other fields. I have a parent view with a list, the list holds multiple NewExercise() views which each have 2 TextFields and 2 Pickers. I am trying to find someway that each instance of the NewExercise() is connected to an Exercise object. As you adjust the state properties of a certain NewExercise() view, it simultaneously adjusts of a corresponding Exercise. For example, changing the name in `NewExercise()[0]` changes the name of `Exercise[0]`. `NewExercise()[1]` changes `Exercise[1]` and so on. Then, when the "Create" button is pressed on the parent view, all the Exercise objects are put into an array.

So my main question is:

How do I get each of these views to correspond with an Exercise? Something like `NewExercise()[1]` is linked to `Exercise[1]`. So adjusting the field in the view changes the corresponding attribute of the Exercise.

My code is a bit long to include here but I have a diagram of how it looks and how I would like it to function:
[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nTo6.png)

Nonetheless, Let me know If it would be useful to provide any code. Or if I'm going in the wrong direction. I'm rather new to swift so anything helps.

Comment: Can you watch the WWDC videos to first understand SwiftUI and Data Flow through SwiftUI and also Combine. It shows examples that way you will have a better understanding.

Comment: @user1046037 Alright I will. Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@State` & `@Binding` property wrappers to achieve this. Your `NewExercise` View should have a `@State var exercise: Exercise` where exercise would look like:

```
struct Exercise {
    var exerciseName: String
    // ... other properties here
}
```

And in your NewExercise View you should have something like this:

```
struct NewExercise: View {
    @State var exercise: Exercise <-- State is owned by the view

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Placeholder", text: $exercise.exerciseName) <-- This is a binding
    }
}
```

Further Explanation: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/226/